# Ms-access query performance

Tags: performance, ms-access, query-performance

I have a sub-form displayed in datasheet view that has a record source like this:

```
    SELECT MyTable.*, myFunction(MyTable.id) as my_result FROM MyTable
```

Where `myFunction()` is a vba function that makes a call to a MySQL stored procedure.

The problem is that `myFunction()` is getting called far too often. For example it gets called whenever the focus is moved from column to column within the same record even though the record remains unchanged. Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Should myFunction() return the same value for every row in the subform record set?

Comment: @HansUp well spotted! And no it shouldn't. I over simplified the original question.

Answer (score 0):

When the focus is given to a linked field, the values of fields are refreshed.
No "simple" solution to your question.

But, if you can do some changes in the access database, you could :
- create a process that fill a field in MyTable with the "myFunction()" result
- call this process each time you display the sub-form or each time the current record change in the sub-form

Or you can :
- add a not detached field to your sub-form
- put in it by code the result of "myFunction()" call each time the current record change in your sub-form

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like MyFunction() should not be called in the SQL statement but in the presentation layer, e.g., as the ControlSource of a control on the form you're using to display your data.